# Compare current and all next value in records in map in spark

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark

I am new to scala. Sample data :

```
1,"jack",34.5
2,"jackk",14.5
3,"jacky",24.5
4,"jack",64.5
And many more.
```

I want to compare each filed of first record with all other field, then second with all other and so on. (Please don't consider Syntaxs)
I have written below code :

```
    val data = sc.parallalize(Seq((1,"jack",34.5),
        (2,"jackk",14.5),
        (3,"jacky",24.5),
       (4,"jack",64.5))

   val res = data.map{f => 
          val rr = f._1.equals(f._1)   //here same field compare with each other But I want to compare current record with all next records.
          Row(rr)  
        }
```

Example:

```
"jack" with "jackk"
"jack" with "jacky"
"jack" with "jack"
"jackk" with "jacky"
"jackk" with "jack"
"jacky" with "jack"
```

I am using `.map` because i want code should be executed on cluster.

Please Give some suggestion.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you consider pattern matching?

Comment: Please Don't consider pattern matching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this:

```
data.cartesian(data).map(pair => compare(pair._1, pair._2))
```

but be aware that 'cartesian' operation takes N*N space.